# Where does Keychain Access store Certificate files?

Tags: xcode, certificate

I want to submit a certificate request, but I don't want to create a new certificate (I already have one). Where is it stored because I want to upload that file.

Comment: If you already have a certificate, why would you want to submit the same certificate request?

Comment: To join another developer team.

Answer (score 0):

How about you export them as suggested in the link below?

http://www.utexas.edu/its/help/user-certs/804

1. In Keychain, select the certificate
2. Select File > Export